# Tools for creating AnimatedVectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, android-vectordrawable

I really like the AnimatedVectorDrawable capabilities added to Android.
Any nice tools to create such animations?

E.g. Any tools to create animations [like described here](https://lewismcgeary.github.io/posts/animated-vector-drawable-pathMorphing/):
[image]

**EDIT:**

So far I have found these tools (that help a little):

- [VectAlign](https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign)
- [AnimatedVectorMorphingTool](https://github.com/MathiasSeguy-Android2EE/AnimatedVectorMorphingTool)
- [SVGO](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

Comment: Do you want specific vector drawables to be generated or are you ok with just svg morphing paths?

Comment: Yes, morphing paths specifically. I'm able to create svg's, I can align them, but still the morphing looks unnatural.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Found two awesome sites.
AndroidIconAnimator, this is a web-based tool for creating AnimatedVectorDrawables. And Shapeshifter, good control over how to morph paths.

**UPDATE 07-09-2017**

Both tools are now merged into one really good solution. It took me sometime to understand how to use it, but once you see it, it is a very capable tool

[Shapeshifter.design](https://shapeshifter.design/)

Thanks 2 Roman Nurik & Alex Lockwood.

Comment: Roman Nurik and I are planning on merging our two projects together (I'm the one who made Shape Shifter, Roman made Android Icon Animator), so stay tuned. :)

Comment: Cool tutorial about shape.shifter here: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/create-your-own-animated-vector-drawable-on-android-app-3f8fa9bb08c3

Answer (score 2):

This question is old. My answer may help future readers.

It is very simple to create animations like the one shown by the questioner. We ourselves can create the animations like the one shown. First, create a VectorDrawable. Eg below:

my_vector_drawable.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="800dp"
        android:height="800dp"
        android:viewportWidth="800.0"
        android:viewportHeight="800.0">

    <path
        android:name="a_circle"
        android:pathData="M  250   200
        q   -86     02    -140     57.5
        t   -57    135.5
        q   -03     93      67    156
        q    59     52     135     50
        q    71    -02     132    -54
        q    66    -56      66   -146
        q    00    -80     -45   -129
        q   -68    -72    -158    -70   "

        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeColor="#f00f"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:trimPathEnd="0"
        android:strokeWidth="32"/>



</vector>
```

my_animated_vector_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:drawable="@drawable/my_vector_drawable">

    <target
        android:name="a_circle"
        android:animation="@animator/my_animation"/>

</animated-vector>
```

my_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:repeatMode="restart"/>
</set>
```

The first file contains the picture data. The third file contains the animation data. The second file links the first and the second.

You can create the three blank files. Copy and paste the contents given above into your files.

You place the first two files in the drawable folder. The third you place in "animator" folder. Both of those folders find the place in the res folder.

You may create a layout file with an ImageView in it. You may give the AnimatedVectorDrawable file as the drawable (android:src="my_animated_vector_drawable").

In your activity set content view to the layout. Also, inflate the ImageView.

```
(myImage=((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageview name);
myImage.getDrawable.start():
```

Then see the fun. You can have several targets in the AnimatedVectorDrawable file. You can have several ObjectAnimators in the animation file under set...

The animation shown in your question is path morphing. Even path morphing example is there in the documentation which is also simple. I leave it to you to experiment.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer shapeshifter.design when I need 5+ vectors to animate individually

Answer (score 1):

You could use Airbnb's lottie library. It makes shipping animated design paths in After Effects to Animated Vector Drawables suitable for android. I think it would be the best solution if you have a decent skill in animating vector paths in After Effects because of the flexibility.

Here's a video that describes the full process of conversion and rendering
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs6GOlgUSc8

[Airbnb's Lottie Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f0qR.gif)

#### Some Animated Icons designed using Lottie.

[image]

#### Animated Icons being used in Layouts

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I'm a (hobby) developer, and would like to stay far away from Adobe's solutions.

Comment: lottie does also not work with splash screen on android, where animated vector drawables would add a lot to user experience, it's great tool though